# Laptop configuration: 1 SSD, 1 HD, 2 operating systems

Tags: ssd

I just bought a 500GB SSD and an adaptor for putting a disk in the optical drive container. I want to maintain the old HDD and add to my laptop the new SSD.

I also want to install two different operating systems: Ubuntu and Windows.
I use most of the time Ubuntu and only sometimes (once a couple of months) Windows mainly because of the Adobe suite (Photoshop, Lightroom, ...)

So my question is what is the best configuration for my laptop. In particular:

1. It is better to put the SSD in the optical drive adaptor or the old HDD?
2. Where should I install the two operating systems? It is better to use the SSD for Ubuntu (that I use more often) and the HDD for Windows or should I create partition on the two disks to have the two operating systems in the SSD and data in the HDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is better to put the SSD in the optical drive adaptor or the old HDD?

In theory this does not matter.

The only exception is in some laptops which provide a slower connection to the optical drive. This could limit the performance of your SSD>

> Where should I install the two operating systems?

This is a matter of opinion. The OS's on the SSD will be faster. So if space on the SSD is not an issue you can install both on them.  If you want to save the 20-30GB on the SSD then you could install the windows OS on the HDD.

Personally I would put both on the SSD.